# UIImageView Disappear after remove image

Tags: objective-c

I tried to remove my images one by one; for that it's ok but when I tried to add a new image by my library nothing appear, I think my code removes my UIImageView.

```
-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender {

  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.imageArray count]; i--) {
    UIImageView *view = self.imageArray[i];

    for (view in [self.view.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator])

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            break;

        }

 }

}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? as in are you getting the results you're expecting in this `- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender` function? because when i ran this code there's a few things i was able to notice:
in the first for statement, shouldn't it be `i++` not `i--` ?
`UIImageView *view = self.imageArray[i]`, this line of code is unused because the the following line, `view` is set to `[self.view.subviews ...]`

Comment: Your code looks buggy as @user1967709 points out. I would also suggest that you avoid deleting items from an array that you are enumerating over. The usual technique is to create new NSMutableArray, add all the objects to be deleted to that, and then delete all the objects in the NSMutableArray from the original array.

Comment: Gosh i hate my username d: but @MichaelL, could you explain what you mean in the form of an answer :)

Comment: Since you are a programmer, I will assume that you were born on the 9th of July, 1967.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to remove and add `UIImageView`s from a mutable array, you can use the following the code.

```
//Create and add items to mutable array
NSMutableArray *arr = [@[] mutableCopy];
[arr addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1"]]];
[arr addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2"]]];
[arr addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3"]]];

//Create temp array to to hold items to remove
NSMutableArray *arrWithItemsToRemove = [@[] mutableCopy];

for(UIView *view in arr)
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        [arrWithItemsToRemove addObject:view];

//Remove objects
[arr removeObjectsInArray:arrWithItemsToRemove];

NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Comment: the original @Michael -:) Nice answer, but removeFromSuperview has to be called, so your nice and concise answer is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with the code you are showing. I am not sure why you have two for loops, and self.imageArray[i] is not even valid Objective-C.

So I am going to assume that you have a view (self.view) which contains subviews, some of which are UIImageViews, and that these are the views you wish to remove.

I would do it like this:

```
NSMutableArray* viewsToDelete = [NSMutableArray new]; 
for(UIView* view in self.view.subViews) { 
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]){ 
        [viewsTodDelete addObject:view]; 
    } 
} 
// Now remove these 
for(UIImageView* imageView in viewsToDelete){
    [imageView removeFromSuperView]; 
}
```

Note that [subview removeFromSuperview] will delete the subview from its parents subviews array, and that is a potential source of problems.

I am not sure if my code will solve your original problem, but this code is cleaner and simpler than the code you showed us, so it is a good place to start.

Comment: Thx I will try this! sorry I'm beginner ;)